# Why isn't my firebase notification using the proper icon?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been trying to add a small icon to my firebase push notification. I was able to create a notification in the app (just for testing), where the icon works fine, but for some reason, firebase just wont use the icon when creating a notification. There's a blank grey circle in the top left of it.

My icon is the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZVBc.png

My firebase notification looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEBFD.png

(notice the blank grey circle in the top left)

My manifest file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chickentendersubsonsale">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_name" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Firebase Messaging documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest),

> **Within the application component,** metadata elements to set a default notification icon and color. Android uses these values whenever incoming messages do not explicitly set icon or color.

You've added the `<meta-data>` element within your `<activity>` component. You need to move it to be directly within the `<application>` level:

```
<application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_name" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the icon in the serverside code.

If you are using node.js to send Firebase notifications:

```
var message = {
    android: {
        notification: {
            body: "Message body",
            title: "Message title",
            icon: "ic_stat_name",
            channelId: "Your channel"
        },
        priority: "high"
    },
    tokens: "array_deviceid"
};
admin.messaging().sendMulticast(message)
    .then((batchResponse) => {
        console.log(batchResponse);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

The `icon` takes to value of the name of the drawable resource.
See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.AndroidNotification.html#icon) of `icon` key for details or if you are using another serverside language.

This also allows you to override the default icon for each notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can send notification with data messages with the help of Postman because right now there is not any medium to send the data messages through Firebase Console.

[image]Data messages are handled here in `onMessageReceived()` whether the app is in the foreground or background.
However, notification messages are received only when the app is in the foreground.

So in both cases, we have to take care of that.

When notification messages received default notification pattern is generated and when you send data messages in your notification data payload then you can generate a custom notification as well with your proper layout.

```
private void sendNotification(PendingIntent pendingIntent, String notificationTitle, String notificationBody) {

        String channelId = getString(R.string.channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_image)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                        .setContentText(notificationBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Channel human readable title", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Mainly in your case notification icon size is taken care of as well.

```
Notification Icons  24 px (22px inset)  36 px   48 px   72 px   96 px
```